# How to lazy load constants into rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, lazy-loading

I have a set of API keys that I want to load into the rails environment, for easy and frequent access (without hitting the database). How can I lazy load it:

1) Let's say there is an API_KEY hash in rails environment (that I initialize using an initializer)

2) When I look up for a key, I first look up in API_KEY hash, if not found, I fetch from database, and at the same time add to API_KEY hash, such that it is accessible for all future requests.

3) In case someone changes the the api key, I can update API_KEY hash in case the key exists.

Can someone help me with the calls to create, delete and update the API_KEY hash in the rails environment (from within the code, instead of the initial rails loading)? Will there be a problem in this approach if each passenger thread loads the rails environment separately?

Any other problems that you see with this approach? The data set (number of api keys) is finite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're actually just storing values in a Hash (its being assigned to a constant is immaterial since you're not freezing it or anything) I would use the [block form of `Hash.new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-new). I don't know what your database looks like, but supposing you had these values stored in a model called `APIKey` that has attributes `name` and `value`:

```
API_KEY = Hash.new do |hash, key_name|
  hash[key_name] = APIKey.where(:name => key_name).pluck(:value)
end
```

Now when you access the `API_KEY` hash with a key that doesn't exist, it will query the APIKey model and assign the value of the `value` attribute to that element of the hash. Suppose you have this in your `api_keys` table:

```
name       value
---------  ----------------
S3_ACCESS  0123456789abcdef
```

Then you could access the hash defined above like this:

```ruby
puts API_KEY[:S3_ACCESS]
# Query: SELECT `value` FROM `api_keys` WHERE `name` = 'S3_ACCESS']
# => 0123456789abcdef

puts API_KEY.inspect
# => { :S3_ACCESS => "0123456789abcdef" }

puts API_KEY[:S3_ACCESS]
# No query!
# => 0123456789abcdef
```

If you want to update the value at runtime then you can do it like any hash:

```
API_KEY[:S3_ACCESS] = '5555555555ffffff'
# => "5555555555ffffff"

puts API_KEY.inspect
# => { :S3_ACCESS => "5555555555ffffff" }
```

However, changing the hash will not update the database record.

#### Advanced

If you want the database record to be updated if you update the hash, you'll have to override `Hash#[]=`, and if you're going to go that far you might as well use ActiveRecord directly. For example:

```
class APIKey < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :value

  @@_cached_values = Hash.new do |_cached_values, key_name|
    # This will return nil if there's no record in the database with the
    # given name; alternatively you could use `first!` which would raise a
    # RecordNotFound exception which you could rescue and do something
    # useful with.
    _cached_values[key_name] = self.where(:name => key_name).pluck(:value)
  end

  def self.[](key_name)
    @@_cached_values[key_name]
  end

  def self.[]=(key_name, new_value)
    # If the database already has a value for this key_name, fetch the object;
    # otherwise initialize a new object
    api_key = self.where(:name => key_name).first_or_initialize

    # Update the value and save the record
    api_key.update_attributes!(:value => new_value)

    # Update the cached value
    @@_cached_values[key_name] = new_value
  end
end

puts APIKey[:S3_ACCESS]
# Query:  SELECT `value` FROM `api_keys` WHERE `name` = 'S3_ACCESS'
# => 0123456789abcdef

APIKey[:S3_ACCESS] = '5555555555ffffff'
# Query:  UPDATE `api_keys` SET `value` = '5555555555ffffff'
#           WHERE `name` = 'S3_ACCESS'
# => '5555555555ffffff'

APIKey[:NEW_KEY] = 'new_val'
# Query:  INSERT INTO `api_keys` (`name`, `value`)
#           VALUES ('NEW_KEY', 'new_val')
# => 'new_val'
```

With this kind of implementation `APIKey[:S3_ACCESS]` would work the same as the API_KEY example above; and `APIKey[:S3_ACCESS] = 'foo'` would perform an `UPDATE` or `INSERT` as necessary.

This is probably reinventing the wheel, though; at this point you're probably better off using one of the many [configuration management gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Configuration_Management) people much smarter than me have written. Also, let us not forget [The Twelve-Factor App](http://12factor.net/), which exhorts us to [store config in the environment](http://12factor.net/config).

P.S. You get ridiculous overimplementation points if you define `APIKey.const_missing` so you can do `APIKey::S3_ACCESS` instead of `APIKey[:S3_ACCESS]`.

Comment: Jordan thank you for taking out time to answer this. Does updating the hash like `API_KEY[:S3_ACCESS] = '5555555555ffffff'`ensure that it will be updated across all passenger threads (or in other multi threaded servers). Or will I run into problems of it not being consistent across threads?

The initial access is fine, even if it is per thread (as it will eventually fetch the value from db for each thread), but I can run into problems if the update doesn't happen across all threads, as one passenger process will have the correct key, and the other wouldn't. Or am I over-thinking this?

Comment: I don't think changing the value in one Passenger instance will change it in another. Here's a question: How often do the values change, and how often do you access them? If you're dealing with multiple Rails processes rolling your own solution might be more trouble than it's worth. Personally I'd just use a plain ActiveRecord model, since Rails automatically does per-request caching of database requests (except in development), and if I encountered a performance issue look into using Rails' [caching API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) directly.

Comment: It's an API where the API key (for different devs) is required in every request, so I wanted to keep it in memory for easy access. I am not using ActiveRecord, but mongodb via mongoid. So I could rely on mongo caching, but I wanted to avoid hitting the db.

Or probably I will go ahead with some kind of rolling restart mechanism every 2 hours, or set some timestamp in memory, and clear the API_KEY hash every 1 hour (add that code to the block itself, on a new fetch). #justThinking